# Is there a native way to combine a std::merge() and a std::transform() into one loop?

Tags: c++

Let's say I want to combine two sorted `std::vector<std::string>`s and into a list that:

1. Is in sorted order
2. Has every letter capitalized

Of course, I can first use `std::merge()` on the two lists, and then call `std::transform` on the resulting vector to uppercase each string (some rough code below):

```
std::vector<std::string> list1 = {"a", "c", "d"};
std::vector<std::string> list2 = {"b", "e"}

std::vector<std::string> result;

// Merge the two lists into result
std::merge(list1.begin(), list1.end(), list2.begin(), list2.end(), std::back_inserter(result));

// Now uppercase each string
std::transform(result.begin(), result.end(), result.begin(), [](auto& elem) { return toupper(elem); });

// result should now contain {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E"}
```

But this seems wasteful because we're doing two loops. Instead, is there an elegant way to perform the transform on each element as it gets added to the new list to avoid the final loop?

I understand it is straightforward to implement myself, but was hoping there was a more elegant or idiomatic way to do it.

I've tried Googling around and looking through the cpp reference, but can't seem to find anything.

Comment: Can you post the code that does exactly what you want in two loops so we can make sure we understand exactly what you're asking for?

Comment: Are you restricted to C++11 or are you mistagging?

Comment: Updated the question with some rough C++ pseudo code (not sure if it completely compiles) and yes, it was a mistag, I have removed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, we can - but only because this transformation doesn't change the ordering, so we can apply it first to each of the lists before merging:

```
    auto toupper_view = std::views::transform(toupper);
    std::ranges::merge(list1 | toupper_view,
                       list2 | toupper_view,
                       std::back_inserter(result));
```

Full demo (including the pieces implied by but missing from the question):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <locale>
#include <string>
#include <ranges>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> const list1 = {"a", "c", "d"};
    std::vector<std::string> const list2 = {"b", "e"};
    std::vector<std::string> result;

    static auto const toupper = [](std::string s)
    {
        static auto const upcase_char
            = [](char c){ return std::toupper(c, std::locale::classic()); };
        std::ranges::transform(s, s.begin(), upcase_char);
        return s;
    };

    // Combined transform and merge
    static auto const toupper_view = std::views::transform(toupper);
    std::ranges::merge(list1 | toupper_view,
                       list2 | toupper_view,
                       std::back_inserter(result));

    // result should now contain {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E"}
    std::vector<std::string> const expected{"A", "B", "C", "D", "E"};
    return !std::ranges::equal(result, expected);
}
```

---

Alternatively, we could write an output iterator adapter to use in place of the `std::back_insert_iterator` we have here, to apply the transformation as we write to the output collection.  That's substantially more work, so probably only worthwhile for transformations that don't preserve ordering.

Comment: Thanks, this is really helpful! The pipe operator is new to me - it looks like that's a C++20 feature (RangeAdaptorClosure). Is there a feature similar this that would work for earlier C++ versions?

Comment: The operator is not new of course, but overloading it to provide views is part of the Ranges feature that was adopted for C++20.  It was developed as [a stand-alone library](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3) so if you're stuck with an older compiler, you might be able to experiment with that until your compiler is updated.

Answer (score 2):

Not that I know of, but it is not hard to write a function for this.
At least you will have something reusable this way ;)

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

auto str_toupper(const std::string& str)
{
    std::string result{str};
    std::transform(result.begin(), result.end(), result.begin(), [](const char c) { return static_cast<char>(std::toupper(c)); });
    return result;
}

template<typename collection_t, typename transform_fn_t>
auto merge_and_transform(const collection_t& values1, const collection_t& values2, transform_fn_t transform)
{
    collection_t result(values1.size() + values2.size());
    auto it = result.begin();
    for (auto& value : values1) *it++ = transform(value);
    for (auto& value : values2) *it++ = transform(value);
    return result;
}

int main()
{

    std::vector<std::string> list1{ "a", "c", "d" };
    std::vector<std::string> list2{ "b", "e" };
    
    auto result = merge_and_transform(list1, list2, str_toupper);

    for (const auto& c : result) std::cout << c;

}
```

Comment: Obligatory reminder that the argument of `toupper` must be converted to `unsigned char` to avoid UB on negative chars.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Yeah, I never really understood why toupper's argument isn't a char in the first place

Comment: This isn't merging things. It is just appending isn't it? I thought the OP wanted to leverge the merge algorithm.

Comment: It's because it has to handle `EOF`, so it can be used directly with values from `getchar()`.  I know that provokes another "_why?_", but it gets you one level deeper.  The `<ctype.h>` functions might derive originally from the B language, before `char` was invented.

Comment: @TobySpeight Thanks, I go way back... but not to B ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can create an iterator, that inserts the value after applying the transform you wanted. Not really elegant or idiomatic.

```cpp
template<class Q> struct map_iter {
  using value_type = typename Q::value_type;
  explicit map_iter(Q& q, value_type(&f)(value_type)) : q_(&q), f(f) {}
  void push_back(value_type value) const { q_->push_back(f(value)); }
  Q* q_;
  value_type(&f)(value_type);
};

std::string str_toupper(std::string s){
  std::transform(s.begin(), s.end(), s.begin(),
                 [](unsigned char c){ return std::toupper(c); });
  return s;
}

int main(){
  std::vector<std::string> l1 = {"a", "c", "d"};
  std::vector<std::string> l2 = {"b", "e"};
  std::vector<std::string> result;
  auto m = map_iter(result, str_toupper);
  std::merge(l1.begin(), l1.end(), l2.begin(), l2.end(), std::back_inserter(m));
  for(auto e : result) std::cout << e;
}
```

I'm not sure everything is perfect, but it works.

got the back iterator idea: https://quuxplusone.github.io/blog/2023/10/01/quick-custom-iterator/

Comment: That's an idea, but `map_iter` is a container adapter rather than an _iterator_ adapter, so the name is perhaps misleading.  I was thinking of wrapping an output iterator (`transform_iter(std::back_inserter(m), toupper)`) so that it would work for other targets (e.g. we could wrap a `std::ostream_iterator` with it).

Comment: I agree, it was misnamed. Directly dealing with iterator, instead of underlying container is better.